# How to get new screws for HP Dv7 laptop

Tags: hp-pavilion, laptop-repair

The other day I have noticed that there are 3 screws missing from the bottom of my 3 month old HP Pavilion dv7t-7000 laptop.

This is causing me various problems such as an unstable screen, and who knows what else soon. My laptop is still under the basic warranty, however, I live outside the USA where I purchased it.

What is the best way to get replacement screws for my laptop besides looking around the house and trying to find one that fits?

Let me know if you need pictures

Comment: Laptop service centres will sell them to you at a small price - check the local shops...

Comment: Measure one of the remaining ones? Go to a shop? Buy a selection online? If only 3 months old, contact HP or the shop you got it from and ask for them!

Comment: thanks for these suggestions, but as i said, I live abroad, in the philippines in fact, so it is impossible for me to go to where i bought it, and there really aren't any local shops here.

plus one for the idea of mesuaring a remaining screw

Comment: Check online for a maintenance manual.  I haven't looked at HP, but I did use a Dell manual for disassembling a laptop in order to replace the CPU, and each screw was described by diameter (implies metric thread count) and length.

Comment: Contact HP tech support.  They might just stick a few in an envelope and mail it to you to keep you a happy customer.

Comment: Yeah, well, hp is pretty useless with customer support... wound up having to complain to the ceo office for them to give me service at all